# Can't use VM VirtualBox "VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes"

Tags: virtualbox

I can't use VirtualBox. When I tried to create a ubuntu in it, after powering the virtual box on it gives this as output.
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Ubuntu GNOME.

> VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes
>   (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).
>
> Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) Component: ConsoleWrap
>   Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

Please help me fix this.

Comment: What do you mean by powering virtual box? Do you mean powering the Ubuntu vm you created?
Also do you have virtualization active on your  computer?

Comment: *VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes*, means **disabled in the BIOS**. Go and check it

Comment: If your computer CPU supports VT-x it must be enabled in BIOS. If not (supported and enabled) you are limited to run 32 bits VM's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to make sure that your cpu supports **VT-x** aka virtualization.

Go to [intel's website](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/search.html) and and type your cpu's name and find the specifications and see if VT-x is supported by your cpu.

If is supported enter your bios and search for a option named VT-x virtualization or intel virtualization or just virtualization and enable that and try again virtualbox.

If your cpu supports intel's **VT-d** known simply as **KVM** there is a high chance that you missing a **huge privilege**, for details please see [HERE.](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/FAQ)