# VirtuaBox in Ubuntu 18.04 Issues with Win10.ISO Installation

Tags: dual-boot, virtualbox, virtualization

I'm running Ubuntu/Windows10 (both with latest updates) on an ASUS Intel i7 with 8gb Ram and a 1Tb HDD.
I'm intending to dump Windows completely and just go with Ubuntu. However, I have 1 piece of Windows based software that I use constantly and there is no Linux alternative. I downloaded the Windows 10 ISO. I installed VirtualBox and set up everything and hit start and this is what I got;

**Failed to open a session for the virtual machine WIN10.
VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).
Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}**

According to VirtualBox System->Acceleration, Paravirtualisation Interface is set to 'NONE'; Hardware Virtualisation is set to 'Enable VT-x/AMD-V and to 'Enable Nested Paging'

There is no mention of VT-x in the BIOS (I'm assuming that's the ASUS BIOS)

Sorry if this is long-winded but I don't know how else to frame the question.

Any advice will be gratefully recieved. (I'm an old duffer so please be kind).

Comment: In some BIOSes it is named `Virtualization` instead of  `VT-x`.  If EFI BIOS it might be this:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttR1U.png

Comment: Brilliant. That solved my problem.WIN10 now running in Virtual Box without any problems. Many thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't use VM VirtualBox "VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/884706/cant-use-vm-virtualbox-vt-x-is-disabled-in-the-bios-for-all-cpu-modes)