# Ubuntu not starting on Virtual Box

Tags: 22.04, virtualbox

I've installed Ubuntu on Virtual box, allocating 2 cores from my proccessor, 4 gb of ram and 25 gb of internal memory. However, it displays the "aborted" message and refuses to start. How can I solve it?
[image]

Comment: You must enable virtualization in your host machine's BIOS, as has been answered many, many times on this site.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Can you provide a good AU link to answer OP question? Thx.

Comment: @stumblebee https://askubuntu.com/q/884706/243321 just search for "vt-x is disabled in the bios"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't use VM VirtualBox "VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/884706/cant-use-vm-virtualbox-vt-x-is-disabled-in-the-bios-for-all-cpu-modes)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable hardware virtualization technology (VT-x) for use in Virtualbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256792/how-do-i-enable-hardware-virtualization-technology-vt-x-for-use-in-virtualbox)